# If every character is withing the range of 0-9, then strip out any leading zeros

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my first use of regular expressions, so I wanted to post this to see if it looks ok:

```
if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(x)) {
   x = x.replace(/^0+/,'');
}
```

Meaning:

If every character is withing the range of 0-9, then strip out any leading zeros.

Q: Did I do it right?

Comment: There are lots of regular expression testers on the internet. Did you use any of them to test your regular expression?  Or just run the javascript to see what happens.

Comment: I started out with jsfiddle.net, but I don't know if I came up with every scenario.  Like: "Did you try it with null?"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u88b5/

Comment: if you test null, it won't match your regex.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but you can be cleverererer...

```
x = x.replace(/^0+(?=\d+$)/,"");
```

This has the added bonus of cleverness:

```
x = "000000";
x = x.replace(/^0+(?=\d+$)/,"");
alert(x); // 0
```

ie. if the input consists entirely of zeroes, one zero will remain.

Comment: For the confused: (?=...) is called a "lookahead": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-lookahead

Answer (score 1):

If the cleverererer solution is a bit mind-bending while you're learning regexes, you can use the simpler

```
if (/^[0-9]+$/.test(x)) {
   x = x.replace(/^(0+)([0-9]+)/, "$2");
}
```

which replaces the string with the second (i.e. `$2`) capture.

To develop it a little bit, you can tell it not to remember the first capture by using `?:`, which makes it into what is called a *non-capturing group*, in which case the number of the capture you want to keep is `1`:

```
  x = x.replace(/^(?:0+)([0-9]+)/, "$1");
```

**EDIT:**

As Niet the Dark Absol kindly pointed out, as you don't need the first group, don't even put the parentheses around it:

```
   x = x.replace(/^0+([0-9]+)/, "$1");
```

Comment: You don't even need to parenthesise the first group. `/^0+(\d+)$/` would work. Provided you remember to put that `$` at the end.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I've tried it with and without the trailing `$` and it made no difference - I suppose because the `.test` has already established that the remainder of the line is digits.

Comment: Ah, that's true. You still have that `.test`. Okay.